# For Loop and If statement. How to combine in one statement

Tags: vb.net

I have the following for loop on my project:

```
'Range and Range Array variables
Dim rngArray As Object
Dim rngArrayMain(0 To 9) As Excel.Range

rngArrayMain(0) = xlWSEE.Range("I40")
rngArrayMain(3) = xlWSEE.Range("V46")
rngArrayMain(4) = xlWSEE.Range("L48:N48")
rngArrayMain(5) = xlWSEE.Range("L51")
rngArrayMain(6) = xlWSEE.Range("J35")
rngArrayMain(7) = xlWSEE.Range("J53")
rngArrayMain(1) = xlWSEE.Range("B57:B61")
rngArrayMain(2) = xlWSEE.Range("B70")
rngArrayMain(8) = xlWSEE.Range("L47")
rngArrayMain(9) = xlWSEE.Range("O47")

For Each rngArray In rngArrayMain

    With rngArray

        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 10
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Font.ColorIndex = 2 'white

    End With

Next rngArray
```

No problem, works well. However, I have to separate the last two elements of my array because the `Font.ColorIndex = 1` for them.

So basically my for loop would be:
 if array 0-7
    perform this action

if array 8-9
   then perform this action.

How can I fix my code to reflect this change? If the question seems elementary it's because I have not been programming long and what I know is self-taught (google, bing, and a few books).

Thanks.

Comment: I have posted another answer whereby you can combine related cells together using `Application.Combine` and apply formatting to all of it in one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `For` loop instead of a `For Each`, like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To rngArrayMain.Length - 1
    ' First seven items do this (index 0 to 6)
    If i <= 6 Then
        With rngArrayMain(i)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 10
            .Font.Name = "Calibri"
            .Font.ColorIndex = 2 'white
        End With
    Else
        ' Last two items do this
        With rngArrayMain(i)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 10
            .Font.Name = "Calibri"
            .Font.ColorIndex = 1
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Note: If you remove the `With` block, then you would actually save lines of code, because you put the `If` logic around the one property that is different, like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To rngArrayMain.Length - 1
    rngArrayMain(i).Font.Bold = True
    rngArrayMain(i).Font.Size = 10
    rngArrayMain(i).Font.Name = "Calibri"

    If i <= 6 Then
        rngArrayMain(i).Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Else
        rngArrayMain(i).Font.ColorIndex = 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I believe you can still use `With` here, because the property access doesn't need to be directly underneath, i.e. you can do `If i <= 6 Then  .Font.ColorIndex = 2`.

Comment: @Karl: I have posted an example below using `Application.Combine`. It avoid the need of looping and applies the formatting in one go.

Comment: @shahkalpesh - ah, I did not know you could do that, good to know!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim cellsWithColor2 As Range
Dim cellsWithColor1 As Range

Dim xlWSEE As Worksheet
Set xlWSEE = Worksheets("FillTheNameHere")

Set cellsWithColor2 = Application.Union( _
    xlWSEE.Range("I40"), _
    xlWSEE.Range("V46"), _
    xlWSEE.Range("L48:N48"), _
    xlWSEE.Range("L51"), _
    xlWSEE.Range("J35"), _
    xlWSEE.Range("J53"), _
    xlWSEE.Range("B57:B61"), _
    xlWSEE.Range("B70"))

With cellsWithColor2
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .Font.ColorIndex = 2 'white
End With


Set cellsWithColor1 = Application.Union( _
xlWSEE.Range("L47"), _
xlWSEE.Range("O47"))


With cellsWithColor1
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .Font.ColorIndex = 1 'another color
End With
```